# Find vertex coordinates of a square given their distances $p,\>s,\>q,\>r$ to an inner point

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

[image]

The figure represents a square, with P a point inside the square. The four segments are drawn from P to the four vertices of the square and they are named p, q, r, s.

If the bottom-left vertex is at origin and the sides of the square are parallel to the axes (square is drawn in the first quadrant), find the co-ordinates of other three vertices if the measures of p, q, r, s are given.

I'm seeking your help.

Comment: Set up some angles, use the Law of Sines/Cosines. Can you progress?

Comment: Hint: draw perpendiculars to each side that go through $P$. You've just made a lot of right triangles. Go bananas :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it,s a square $C=(0,0); A=(0,w); E=(w,w); D=(w,0)$ where $w$ is the side of the square.

Law of cosines applied to $\triangle APE$ says that $q^2 = r^2 + w^2 - 2rw \cos \angle PAE$.

Applied to to $\triangle APC$ we have $p^2 = r^2+ w^2 - 2rw \cos (90 -\angle PAE)$.

By my reckoning   that should be enough to solve.  If not we can keep going

$r^2 = p^2 + w^2 -2pw \cos(\angle ACP)$.

etc.

If you are into that whole symmetry thing but not into a $w$ coefficient in quadratic equation jazz you can do the interior angles.

$w^2 = r^2 + q^2 - 2rq\cos \theta$

$= r^2 + p^2 - 2rp \cos \eta$

$= p^2 +s^2 - 2ps\cos \zeta$

$= s^2 +q^2 - 2sq\cos \beta$

$\theta + \eta + \zeta + \beta = 360^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $P(x,y)$ and $a$ the side length of the square. Then,

$$x^2+y^2=p^2, \>\>\>
(a-x)^2+y^2=s^2,\>\>\> x^2+(a-y)^2=r^2
$$
The 2nd and 3rd equations leads to
$x= \frac{a^2+p^2-s^2 }{2a}$ and $y= \frac{a^2+p^2-r^2}{2a}$.
Substitute them into the 1st equation to get

$$ a^4 -(s^2+r^2)a^2 +\frac12[(s^2-p^2)^2+ (r^2-p^2)^2]=0
$$

Solve for $a$ to obtain the vertex coordinates $(0,a)$, $(a,0)$ and $(a,a)$ with

$$a= \left(\frac{s^2+r^2}2 +\left( p^2(s^2+r^2)-p^4 -\frac14(s^2-r^2)^2 \right)^{1/2} \right)^{1/2}
$$

Note that $q^2 = s^2+r^2-p^2$ can not be separately specified. For example, $p=3$, $s=7$ and $r=9$ result in $q=11$ and $a=\sqrt{65+7\sqrt{17}}=9.7$.